# Issue installing selenium webdriver through npm

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have installed protractor & trying to install selenium webdriver. I am getting the following error on executing the command

```
 npm install selenium-webdriver
```

Error:

```
node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager:32
filename: 'selenium-server-standalone-' + versions.selenium + '.jar',

TypeError: Cannot read property 'selenium' of undefined
```

I am using the node.js version 0.10.28 (npm - 1.4.9)

Comment: What version of protractor are you using? Did you install protractor globally (npm install protractor -g)?

Comment: you should run node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Comment: That error happens with webdriver-manager update as well.  Did you ever solve this one?